# Woocommerce 3lvl categories list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have shop category list: 
http://www.test.baldoteka.lt/katalogas/baldai

Content on the right show sub categories.

And here is a sub category link:
http://www.test.baldoteka.lt/katalogas/baldai/baro-kavines-baldai-baldai/

Now content on right show products, but i want to display catergory list as in first link.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually your second link is product sub category link so of course that will populate products of that selected sub category. Why you want to load category list in page of sub category?

Comment: Yes it is, but this subcategory have its own categories (sub sub categories), which i want to dispaly.